# Links not taking to class

Tags: css

for some reason my links aren't conforming to my class. What's going on?

```
.greyBoxTxt {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#7b7d7e;
}

a.greyBoxTxt {
    color:#0164a5;
    text-decoration:none;
}

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" valign="top" class="greyBoxTxt">
            <b>Business Banking</b><br />
            <a href="#">eBusiness Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Business Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Commercial Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Non-Profit Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Business Savings</a><br />
            <a href="#">More...
        </a></td>
        <td width="25%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>            <td width="25%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="25%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong: `a.greyBoxTxt` targets anchor elements with the classname `greyBoxTxt`. Something like thie:

```
<a class="greyBoxTxt" href="#">Lorem</a>
```

What you want is an anchor element which is a descendant of an element with classname `greyBoxTxt`:

```
.greyBoxTxt a {
    /* ... */
}
```

Note that in this new selector, the space between the `.greyBoxTxt` and the `a` is actually the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators).

Comment: did this:  

    greyBoxTxt a {
     color:#0164a5;
     text-decoration:none;
    }

still no go

Comment: You're missing the period `.greyBoxTxt a` - the period is the [class name selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html).

Comment: awesome! something so stupid, but i alway had trouble with this. I would alway resort to inline styles. I figured this time, i would just ask. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you're trying to do is more this

```
.greyBoxTxt {
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#7b7d7e;
}

.greyBoxTxt a {
    color:#0164a5;
    text-decoration:none;
}

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="25%" valign="top" class="greyBoxTxt">
            <b>Business Banking</b><br />
            <a href="#">eBusiness Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Business Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Commercial Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Non-Profit Checking</a><br />
            <a href="#">Business Savings</a><br />
            <a href="#">More...
        </a></td>
        <td width="25%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>            <td width="25%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="25%" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The selector a.greyBoxTxt would select something like this, Commercial Checking

Comment: did this:  

    greyBoxTxt a {
     color:#0164a5;
     text-decoration:none;
    }

still no go